# Identity Server connect/token unsupported grant_type error

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have created an Identity Server by using .net core 3.1 but when I tried to get token I'm taking this error.

[image]

[image]

Here is my appsettings.json file

```
"Clients": [
  {
    "ClientId": "portal-api",
    "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": true,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true, //support refresh tokens
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 3600,
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "lxl76J788Cvf1ds8CQJuFYGwTi7e3BXGCRK2JIUekmk=" } ],
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "password", "code" ],
    "AllowedScopes": [ "rest.auth" ],
    "RefreshTokenUsage": "OneTimeOnly",
    "RequireClientSecret": true,
    "Enabled": true
  }
]
```

},

Comment: can you post how you configure IdentityServer in Startup.cs? Are you sure the settings are actually applied from appsettings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly related to your question, but using password grant is against current best practices, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-18#section-2.4 for details.

I would also recommend to not allow multiple grant types for a single client, as this broadens possible attack vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/clients/#defining-clients-in-appsettingsjson) you see that the appsettings should start with the IdentityServer object, like:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "IssuerUri": "urn:sso.company.com",
    "Clients": [
        {
            "Enabled": true,
            "ClientId": "local-dev",
            "ClientName": "Local Development",
            "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "<Insert Sha256 hash of the secret encoded as Base64 string>" } ],
            "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "client_credentials" ],
            "AllowedScopes": [ "api1" ],
        }
    ]
}
```